# How do I change the default value of the "position" category attribute?

Tags: category, category-attribute, position

I would like to update the default position value that products are assigned when they are added to a category. When you update a category from the categories editor, new products are saved with a position of 0. When you add a product to a category via the tree when filling out the product, it saves with a position value of 1.

What I want to do is have items save with a position of 100 instead of 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rewrite the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product::_saveCategories`
Somewhere in there this is this:

```
$data[] = array(
    'category_id' => (int)$categoryId,
    'product_id'  => (int)$object->getId(),
    'position'    => 1
);
```

Replace `1` with `100`.
To rewrite the resource model add this to the `config.xml` of your custom module inside the  global tag

```
<models>
    <catalog_resource>
        <rewrite>
            <product>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Resource_Product</product>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog_resource>
</models>
```

Then create the class `[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Resource_Product` that extends `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product`, copy the method `_saveCategories` to it and replace `1` with `100`.

Comment: Anyone coming here looking (like I was) for the Magento 2 version of this answer, the location is module-catalog/Model/Category/Link/SaveHandler.php