# How do I change the default attribute 'position' in layered navigation?

Tags: attributes, ce-1.9.2.0, position, default-values

I'm organizing my attributes to show in a specific order in layered navigation. To do this I need to set the 'position' value of them all. Magento defaults them to 0 so to put an attribute (say color) at the top of the list, I'll need to change the position of them all, which can get tedious.

What code can I use to reset all my attributes to 100 and to change the defaults?

Bonus: To exclude specific attributes from being reset such as `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/attributes')->excludeFilter(array('color', 'size')->walk('delete');`

Note: Changing the default position of a *product* has [already been discussed](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/26222/18509). I'm looking to change the position of the *attribute itself*.

[image: Manage Attributes Page]

ANSWER:
  Thank you saravanavelu for your pointer.

Here is the code I was looking for:

```
UPDATE `catalog_eav_attribute` SET `position`= 100 WHERE `attribute_id` NOT IN (130, 140, 120)
```

where the numbers are attribute codes. Attribute codes are found in the URL of the `Edit Attribute` page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to change the position,

```
//72 is description's attribute id
UPDATE `catalog_eav_attribute` SET `position`= 100 WHERE `attribute_id` = 72
```

Comment: Why do you want me to change the attribute called 'description'?

Comment: this is for example to change the position

Comment: I see the table in phpmyadmin. Shouldn't the column name be `position`? Also would you be able to try for the `Bonus`. I'm not so great at SQL queries.

Comment: I have updated the answer